# jsdom.env is not a function in herokuapp using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I have an app running in Heroku using node.js.  It was working (like always) previously until some time ago.  I wasn't receiving anymore notifications.  I haven't changed any codes in the server-side nor client-side.  I receieved the following errors in Heroku.

**Error Log in Heroku**

```
2017-07-18T04:16:42.967561+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: jsdom.env is not a function
2017-07-18T04:16:42.967563+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/server.js:77:11
2017-07-18T04:16:42.967564+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2017-07-18T04:16:42.967565+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2017-07-18T04:16:42.967566+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
2017-07-18T04:16:42.967566+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2017-07-18T04:16:42.967567+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
2017-07-18T04:16:42.967568+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2017-07-18T04:16:42.967568+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
2017-07-18T04:16:42.967569+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/server.js:27:5
2017-07-18T04:16:42.967569+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "*",
    "express": "*",
    "jquery": "*",
    "jsdom": "*",
    "web-push": "*"
  }
}
```

I have the following also at the top of my javascript file.

```
var $ = require('jquery'),
    jsdom = require("jsdom"),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    webPush = require('web-push'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

So I am not sure why am I receiving this error.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `*` to specify your dependency version. Lock down to specific versions to ensure that the same code runs remotely as locally. Also make sure to specify the [`engines`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines) namespace in your `package.json` with your `npm` and `node` versions.

Comment: here is what I did.  Still has that `jsdom.env` error.  locally its working fine.  

`
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "jquery": "~2.2.0",
    "jsdom": "^11.1.0",
    "web-push": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.1"
  }
}

`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, it was connected to the use of ` * `.  The server was getting the latest version of the plugin and I didnt know that the API was updated.  All good now.